# 500 email delivery failure mx records look fine

Tags: email, records, mx-record

I am getting this error when I try to send to an email address that belongs to a friend of mine who is hosting his site on my hosting account, but using his email from the place he registered the domain.

```
"Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
nick@domain.com
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain.
We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the
cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 #5.1.0
Address rejected nick@domain.com (state 14)."
```

So the domain is registered at luckyregister.com where there is 2 email addresses.
The DNS was updated to point to my server so the site is hosted at arvixe.com
Within the Cpanel of domain.com, I changed the MX record to "smtp.secureserver.net" with priority 0.
I added the CNAME email.domain.com -> email.secureserver.net

Its been over 24 hours and I am still getting this error returned when I try to send nick@domain.com an email. I feel terrible leaving him without email for days, so I am ready for your help!

**note that domain.com is substituted for his domain for his privacy

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer...

For whatever reason, luckyregister deleted the original email accounts when the domain nameservers were updated to point to arvixe. So here I am thinking it is an MX record issue, but when I gained access to my friends account to look further into things, I found that the accounts didn't even exist!